# How to access current input in Razor form so I can add it to a query?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a table that has sortable headers, paging (using `PagedList`), with filters with a submit button (using `HtmlForm Get`). Using any of the filters, or clicking the headers, or page numbers should do query Get and update the table with the same querystring. However, I have a problem:

The headers and pages are action links, and the filters themselves were created using `@Html.TextBox`, `DropDownList`, etc... and have a submit button

In my `ActionLink` I need to be able to pass all of the parameters including the values currently in the filter form:

```
@Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index",
                 new {Value1 = (Value in TextBox),
                      Value2 = ViewBag.Something,
                      Value3 = ect...})
```

and, there is also a submit button for the filters, and if that is pressed I need to be able to add the additional information to the query string from my Viewbag which holds the sorting header value and need to send the value from the model with the pagenumber.

Is there anyway at all to do what I am trying to do?

(I have thought about turning the submit button from an input to an action link, but I still don't know how to get the current values out of `Html.TextBox` etc)...

**EDIT**

I created a new filter object, that I now send as a parameter to my controller. However, I have a some action links for the headers of my table and for pages. I don't know how I can change my filter object when they are clicked without creating an action for every header and page button in my controller. Is that even a bad idea? For example:

```
ActionResult NextPage(Filter filter);...
ActionResult Header1(Filter filter);...
...
```

If I don't do it this way...I don't know how to know which action link the user clicked...and I can't use routedatadictionary because I can only send my filter object, or a bunch of parameters not both...

Another idea would be to send all of the filter model's properties, plus the links name as in a string query then rebuild the filter in the controller...

Comment: What model do you use in the view?

Comment: Atm, the Model only holds the values to populate the table. And does not hold any filter, sorting, or any other data, though I could modify it to do such. If I add this to the model... I need to be able to pass the model using an action link, which I thought is not possible, or am I wrong?

Comment: Passing the model is not impossible, you can include the additional fields, although i think there should be a seperation of concerns. You can make a sort of grid model, that accepts a data model as parameter. I agree with Brent Echols with the hidden input fields for the sorting and page number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a model! So in the Action "Index", make its parameters accepts SomeModel model. Just bind all of the inputs to it and it will automatically submit. To take care of persisting the ViewBag, you have the right idea up there where you just say new { Value1 = ViewBag.Something }. If you really want to make it even more MVC-ish, just make a field in the model for whatever the viewbag holds, and then render an Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeField). Hope this helps!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model, SomeValue value, ...)
{
     //Do whatever filtering you have to do, or redirects, or w/e it is you want

     return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I see, but when the user presses the action links, for the sortable headers or page numbers, I need it submit the model, can I pass my model as a parameter? @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new {Model1 = @Model}) ?

Comment: ohhh I see whats going on... I think I misunderstood a bit at first... Do all of the ActionLinks go to "Index"? If so, just use a form and submit buttons. I'm 70% sure you can just pass the model like you put in the comment though

Comment: Well I have one big problem, and thats you can only pass the model, or pass parameters, not both. But, I need the model to change based on which action link is clicked. =(, is there a way I can change the model based on a particular action link? (The only way I can see doing this is have a special action in my controller for each header of the table: Column1(Object object)... Column2... ect... then I can have it sort the right one...but thats alot of repeating and not very dynamic